# как определить сайт открыт через telegram web app или через браузер?

Tags: javascript, telegram

Как определить сайт открыт через telegram web app или через браузер?

```
    <h3 id="test"></h3>
    <script>
        let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
        try {
            tg.initDataUnsafe.user.id;
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'через телеграм'
        }
        catch (_) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'через сайт'
        }
    </script>
```

Я пробовал так, но если открыть телеграм веб, через код элемента найти iframe web app'а и открыть его scr, то будет считаться что сайт открыт через телеграм.
Как этого избежать?